# how to konw the convergence of the sequence?

Tags: calculus

Study the sequence defined by the recursion:

$$
u_{0}>-1,\quad u_{n+1}=\sqrt{\frac{1+u_{n}}{2}}.
$$

i write

$$
\text{Behavior: }u_{n+1}>u_n\mathrm{~if~}\sqrt{\frac{1+u_n}2}>u_n
$$

Monotonicity: We show that if $u_n> - 1, $ then $u_{n+ 1}> u_n$

$$
\text{Solving for monotonicity: }\sqrt{\frac{1+u_n}2}>u_n\Rightarrow\frac{1+u_n}2>u;
$$

$$
\Rightarrow1+u_n>2u_n^2\Rightarrow2u_n^2-u_n-1<0
$$

i don't know next step